# Property of Javascript object doesnt get set

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, properties

got a little javascript problem:
I have a set of to separate .js files, one acts as "class", this is my parser-"class", it basicly stores the content of a CSV file and a random part of it (csv-file is "country;capital"), parsing works fine:

```
var allLocations;
var rndLocations;

function CSVparser() {
this.allLocations = new Array;
this.rndLocations = new Array;

//parses the CSV into an Array ("Country;City")
this.parse = function(parser) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "ressource/capitalCountryList.txt",
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(data) {
            parser.allLocations = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var min = 0;
            var max = parser.allLocations.length - 1;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                var rndIndex = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
                parser.rndLocations.push(parser.allLocations[rndIndex]);
            }
        }
    });
  };
}
```

In my main class I now initiate a parser likes this and call the parse()-function:

```
var parser = new CSVparser();
parser.parse(parser);
```

If I now log the parser in my main class (`console.log(parser)`) I'm able to see the contents of the parser's properties (like for example the `rndLocations` array). But if I want to access this array inside of my main class via

```
parser.rndLocations;
```

the array is empty.

Whats the problem there? Sorry for my not so perfect English! Appreciate the Help!

Comment: One word: **asynchronous**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call - pushing on the result data is just a *side-effect* like assigning to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, i now set the ajax-async property to "false". guess now it works...but thats deprecated...will look at the other solution from your link!

Comment: I recommend using the Promises/A callback approach for flexibility and consistency - forcing a synchronous request often runs counter to modern designs and may result in less-than-ideal user experiences.

Comment: Ajax should not be use as Synchronous because BLOCK complete the UI for the user and create a no pleasure interaction on the user experience.